# Passing Extra Data Into a Function

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing, dlib

I am using the dlib optimization library for C++ specifically the following function:

```
template <
    typename search_strategy_type,
    typename stop_strategy_type,
    typename funct, 
    typename funct_der, 
    typename T
    >
double find_max (
    search_strategy_type search_strategy,
    stop_strategy_type stop_strategy,
    const funct& f, 
    const funct_der& der, 
    T& x, 
    double max_f
);
```

Functions f and der are designed to take a vector of the data parameters being modified to obtain the maximum value of my function. However my function being maximized has four parameters (one is my dataset and the other is fixed by me). However I can't pass these as inputs to my f and der functions because of the format they are supposed to have. How do I get this data into my functions? I am currently trying the below (I hard set variable c but for vector xgrequ I read data from a file each time I process the function.

```
//Function to be minimized
double mleGPD(const column_vector& p)
{
    std::ifstream infile("Xm-EVT.csv");
    long double swapRet;
    std::string closeStr;
    std::vector<double> histRet;

    //Read in historical swap data file
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            infile >> swapRet;
            histRet.push_back(swapRet);
        }
    }
    sort(histRet.begin(), histRet.end());
    std::vector<double> negRet;
    //separate out losses
    for (unsigned c = 0; c < histRet.size(); c++)
    {
        if (histRet[c] < 0)
        {
            negRet.push_back(histRet[c]);
        }
    }
    std::vector<double> absValRet;
    //make all losses positive to fit with EVT convention
    for (unsigned s = 0; s < negRet.size(); s++)
    {
        absValRet.push_back(abs(negRet[s]));
    }
    std::vector<double> xminusu, xmu, xgrequ;
    int count = absValRet.size();
    double uPercent = .9;
    int uValIndex = ceil((1 - uPercent)*count);
    int countAbove = count - uValIndex;
    double c = (double)absValRet[uValIndex - 1];
    //looking at returns above u
    for (unsigned o = 0; o < uValIndex; ++o)
    {
        xmu.push_back(absValRet[o] - c);
        if (xmu[o] >= 0)
        {
            xgrequ.push_back(absValRet[o]);
            xminusu.push_back(xmu[o]);
        }
    }
    double nu = xgrequ.size();
    double sum = 0.0;
    double a = p(0);
    double b = p(1);

    for (unsigned h = 0; h < nu; ++h)
    {
        sum += log((1 / b)*pow(1 - a*((xgrequ[h] - c) / b), -1 + (1 / a)));
    }
    return sum;
}
//Derivative of function to be minimized
const column_vector mleGPDDer(const column_vector& p)
{
    std::ifstream infile("Xm-EVT.csv");
    long double swapRet;
    std::string closeStr;
    std::vector<double> histRet;

    //Read in historical swap data file
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            infile >> swapRet;
            histRet.push_back(swapRet);
        }
    }
    sort(histRet.begin(), histRet.end());
    std::vector<double> negRet;
    //separate out losses
    for (unsigned c = 0; c < histRet.size(); c++)
    {
        if (histRet[c] < 0)
        {
            negRet.push_back(histRet[c]);
        }
    }
    std::vector<double> absValRet;
    //make all losses positive to fit with EVT convention
    for (unsigned s = 0; s < negRet.size(); s++)
    {
        absValRet.push_back(abs(negRet[s]));
    }
    std::vector<double> xminusu, xmu, xgrequ;
    int count = absValRet.size();
    double uPercent = .9;
    int uValIndex = ceil((1 - uPercent)*count);
    int countAbove = count - uValIndex;
    double c = (double)absValRet[uValIndex - 1];
    //looking at returns above u
    for (unsigned o = 0; o < uValIndex; ++o)
    {
        xmu.push_back(absValRet[o] - c);
        if (xmu[o] >= 0)
        {
            xgrequ.push_back(absValRet[o]);
            xminusu.push_back(xmu[o]);
        }
    }
    column_vector res(2);
    const double a = p(0);
    const double b = p(1);
    double nu = xgrequ.size();
    double sum1 = 0.0;
    double sum2 = 0.0;
    for (unsigned h = 0; h < nu; ++h)
    {
        sum1 += ((xgrequ[h]-c)/b)/(1-a*((xgrequ[h]-c)/b));
        sum2 += log(1 - a*((xgrequ[h] - c) / b));
    }
    res(0) = sum1;//df/da
    res(1) = sum2;//df/db
    return res;
}
```

Here is what my actual function call looks like:

```
//Dlib max finding
    column_vector start(2);
    start = .1, .1; //starting point for a and b
    find_max(bfgs_search_strategy(), objective_delta_stop_strategy(1e-6), mleGPD, mleGPDDer, start,100);
    std::cout << "solution" << start << std::endl;
```

Comment: Why can't you take the parameters, convert them to the correct type, and pass those?

Comment: The actual code for the find_max(...) function in its header file show only 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of API is very common. It's almost always possible to for `f` and `der` to any *callable*, not just static functions. that is, you can pass a custom class object with operator () to it.

For example

```
struct MyF {
  //int m_state; 
  //   or other state variables, such as 
  std::vector<double> m_histRet;
  // (default constructors will do)

  double operator()(const column_vector& p) const {
    return some_function_of(p, m_state);
  }
};

int main(){
  . . . 
  MyF myf{42};
  // or
  MyF myf{someVectorContainingHistRet};

  // then use myf as you would have used mleGPD
}
```

You need to initiate MyF and MyDer with the same state (`std::vector<double> histRet` I presume.) Either as copies or (const) references to the same state.

**Edit**: More full example:

```
struct MLGDPG_State {
  std::vector<double> xgrequ;
  // . . . and more you need in f or fder
}

MLGDPG_State makeMLGDPG_State(const std::string& filename){
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    std::ifstream infile("Xm-EVT.csv");
    long double swapRet;
    std::string closeStr;
    std::vector<double> histRet;

    //Read in historical swap data file
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            infile >> swapRet;
            histRet.push_back(swapRet);
        }
    }
    sort(histRet.begin(), histRet.end());
    std::vector<double> negRet;
    //separate out losses
    for (unsigned c = 0; c < histRet.size(); c++)
    {
        if (histRet[c] < 0)
        {
            negRet.push_back(histRet[c]);
        }
    }
    std::vector<double> absValRet;
    //make all losses positive to fit with EVT convention
    for (unsigned s = 0; s < negRet.size(); s++)
    {
        absValRet.push_back(abs(negRet[s]));
    }
    std::vector<double> xminusu, xmu, xgrequ;
    int count = absValRet.size();
    double uPercent = .9;
    int uValIndex = ceil((1 - uPercent)*count);
    int countAbove = count - uValIndex;
    double c = (double)absValRet[uValIndex - 1];
    //looking at returns above u
    for (unsigned o = 0; o < uValIndex; ++o)
    {
        xmu.push_back(absValRet[o] - c);
        if (xmu[o] >= 0)
        {
            xgrequ.push_back(absValRet[o]);
            xminusu.push_back(xmu[o]);
        }
    }
    return {std::move(xgrequ)}; 
    // Or just 'return MleGPD(xgrequ)' if you are scared of {} and move
}

//Functor Class, for ion to be minimized
struct MleGPD{
  MLGDPG_State state;  
  double operator()(const column_vector& p) const {   
    auto mu = state.xgrequ.size();
    double sum = 0.0;
    double a = p(0);
    double b = p(1);
    for (unsigned h = 0; h < nu; ++h)
    {
        sum += log((1 / b)*pow(1 - a*((xgrequ[h] - c) / b), -1 + (1 / a)));
    }
    return sum;
};
```

Use the same pattern for a struct `MleGPD_Derivative`.

Usage:

```
const auto state = makeMLGDPG_State("Xm-EVT.csv");
const auto f = MleGPD{state};
const auto der = MleGPD_Derivative{state};

start = .1, .1; //starting point for a and b
find_max(bfgs_search_strategy(), objective_delta_stop_strategy(1e-6), f, der, start,100);
std::cout << "solution" << start << std::endl;
```

Note, that for simple structs like these, it's often fine to use the default constructors, copy constructor etc. Also note http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: Could you provide a short example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes. If you provide example arguments you use for calling max() it would make it more complete.

Comment: Function call added to the question

Comment: Let me try this out. Thanks

Comment: I implemented what was proposed above and I got a Fatal Error in one of the dlib files. Debugging now.

Comment: It *could* be that the library assumes it can copy the functors by copying their memory instead of using correct copying. If that's the case, try changing the member `MLGDPG_State state` to a pointer: `MLGDPG_State * state` and initialize them like `MleGPD{&state}`. Or better, try to find the right mailing list/maintainer.

Comment: I ended up using functors with a class but your help got me going in the right direction. The fatal error was caused by me not having the correct return type in my derivative functor class.